# How to break up a promise in a `then` function

Tags: node.js

Here, says we got a user signup request, we gotta detect whether the username is already token(let's just assumes the data is valid), and if it is, goes on:

```
User
    .getByName(name)
    .then(function (user) {
        // if user is not null, which means the username is already token
        if (user !== null) return res.json({errorCode: 1001})
    })
    .then(function() {
        // Oops, the previous return is captcha here
        // how to break the promise and return the request
        var user = new User({
            name: name
        })
    })
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AS Below. This is the proper way to use promises.

```
var  when = require('when');


checkUser(name)
  .then(function () {
    var user = new User({
      name: name
    })
  }, function (error) {
    // handle error here
  })
}

var function checkUser(name){

   var deferred = when.defer();

   User.getByName(name,function(user){
     user === null ?
       deferred.resolve() : deferred.reject(new Error('Username alreay token'))
   });

   return deferred.promise;   
}
```

Comment: Well, who decides what "is proper"? You could just return Promise.resolve() and Promise.reject() - no need to created a deferred and then resolve it later in a synchronous process...

Comment: @CFrei I do not see any synchronous code, but I do agree the code can be improved the way returning `resolve` and `reject`, which will make this a good example for such problem :)

Comment: @klamtlne though I like your edit, I think that it changes the idea of Waqas Ahmed's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the call to your second `then`, you need to make the first `then` fail. Just add as the last line of `function(user)` a `throw 'User exists'` and the next `then` goes into the reject path, which you didn't have set.

I admit, its an ugly approach, but it would work! ;)

Comment: There are many ugly approaches and this is the top of them.
Please give a suitable example to solve this except this worst approach.

Comment: His question was: How to break up a promise in a `then` function. I answered that question and showed him how to do that. I think he is smart enough to reorganize the rest of the code after he understands the concept. :)

Comment: +1 thanks for showing the right way breaking a promise!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't resolve your promise, you should reject it:

```js
User.getByName(name).then(function(existing) {
    // If user already exists, we should return
    // rejected promise with good rejection reason
    if (existing !== null) return reject {
        message: 'User already exists',
        errorCode: 1001,
        status: 403
    };
    var user = new User({
        name: name
    });
    // ... some staff ..
    return user.save();
}).then(function(user) {
    // ... some other staff ...
    res.json(user);
}).otherwise(function(err) {
    // Something bad happened somewhere in the chain
    res.status(err.status || 400).json({
        message: err.message
        errorCode: err.errorCode
    });
})
```

In my example I'm using universal rejection handler to send error response to the client, because we should send something no matter what happened.

`reject` in my example is a function to return rejected promise. Most promise libraries have such function (e.g. `when.reject`, `Q.reject`), but you may replace it with build-in `throw` statement.

Comment: I just learned `reject` can be used this way, most cases, it's used with deffered: `deffered.reject()`. But I wonder whether I can catch the reject in the next `then` function. (`throw` absolutely works)

Comment: @klamtlne `deffered.reject()` rejects ` `deffered.promise` promise, while `when.reject`/`Q.reject` creates new rejected promise.